# Threaded JLabel with changing icon atop another changing icon

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, paintcomponent

I've already created a JLabel who's image changes back and forth between two frames like this.

```
private class CustomLabel extends JLabel implements Runnable
{       
    ImageIcon car1=new ImageIcon(/*icon*/);//makes the wave equal to the wave in outer class (passing reference)
    ImageIcon car2=new ImageIcon(/*icon*/);
    ImageIcon currentCar;
    int current=0;


    public CustomLabel()
    {
        if(x>0 && y<11)setIcon(wave1);

        new Thread(this).start();//am i starting this right?
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
       while (true) 
       {
        if(current == 0)
        {
        setIcon(wave1); 
        current++;
        }
        else
        {
         setIcon(wave2);
         current--;
        }
        repaint();
        try { Thread.sleep(150); }
        catch (InterruptedException e) { }
       }
   }
}
```

So when i add this JLabel it will alternate between two car pictures.
Firstly am I starting the thread correctly by starting it in the constructor?

Now let's say I want there to be a another animation on top of the cars that that is a 5 framed explosion animation that happens when I click the JLabel. How do I go about overlaying the second threaded animation on a current animation. I feel like I need to override the paintComponent() but I'm not too sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are starting your Thread correctly, but you're making Swing state-changing calls, `setIcon(...)` from within your background thread, and *that* is risky.

Myself, I'd use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to drive my animation as with a timer, all calls in its ActionListener will be made on the Swing event thread, making for a safer loop. I'm not sure that I'd extend JLabel for this, since I'm not changing any of the class's innate behavior. Rather I'd use a JLabel.

I'd also add a MouseListener to my label and on mousePressed, I'd stop this Timer and start the explosion animation Timer.

Comment: I see... thanks for the help. Is there a way I can keep the first animation going and add another animation on top of it though? Is that even possible with a JLabel. Would it be better to use a JPanel to put an icon atop another?

Comment: @user234234234 I'm not sure what you're trying to do -- are you trying to swap JLabels continuously and add another animation on top of that? Your JLabel can show only one ImageIcon at a time, so you'd need to do something else, perhaps draw in the glasspane or some such.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do. Can I use a JPanel and then drawImage on top of the backround?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use a `JLayer` to paint different images (icons) on top of the label.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Decorate Components With the JLayer Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html). The section on `Animating a Busy Indicator` would seem similar to what you want to do.